# Formatting columns in exporting SAS table to Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, sas, export-to-excel

I am automating the exporting of a data set from SAS to Excel using `ODS ExcelXP`:

```
       PURCHASE_    annual_      Minimum_
Obs       APR         fee      Cash_Advance
  1     23.45%       NONE          $10
  2     23.45%       NONE          $10
  3     23.45%       NONE          $10
  4     18.45%       NONE          $10
  5     18.45%       NONE          $10
  6     18.45%       NONE          $10
  7     23.45%       NONE          $10
  8     23.45%       NONE          $10
  9     23.45%       NONE          $10
 10     23.45%       $0
 11     23.45%       $0
 12     23.45%       $0
```

In SAS, the columns are formatted as text and I want all of the columns to be imported as text into Excel.  I've used the following code to create the file using `PROC REPORT`:

```
ods tagsets.ExcelXP path="H:/path"  file="file.xls" style=myStyle
                    options(frozen_headers='yes' WrapText='no'
                            embedded_titles='yes' suppress_bylines='yes'
                            sheet_interval='none' sheet_label=' ' 
                            sheet_name='Solicited'
                            width_points='1' width_fudge='1' 
                            absolute_column_width='100' autofit_height='yes' 
                            zoom='100');
title1;

proc report data=testing2 nowd;
  column purchase_APR annual_fee minimum_cash_advance;
  define purchase_APR / display style(column)={tagattr='format:@'} 'PURCHASE_APR';
  define annual_fee / display style(column)={tagattr='format:@'} 'ANNUAL_FEE';
  define minimum_cash_advance / display style(column)={tagattr='format:@'} 'MINIMUM_CASH_ADVANCE';
run;

ods tagsets.ExcelXP close;
```

However, when opening up the Excel file, the Text fields have been somehow changed from `23.45%`, `$0`, and `$10` (text) to `0.2345`, `0`, and `10` (text) respectively.

How can I get the output in Excel to be just like the data set in SAS?

I have tried using the specific formats to get them to look the same (i.e.`tagattr='format:0.00%'`, etc.) but the output in Excel is numeric and not text format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way would be to modify how the template processes numbers.  You can do that pretty easily in this case.  You could even just comment out a line and one block of code, but here's the really proper answer.

Open the [template](http://support.sas.com/rnd/base/ods/odsmarkup/excltags.tpl) in a text editor.  We're going to add a couple of parameters, and implement them.

First, add the options to the $valid_options array.  There are a bunch of lines like these, add these two more (Around line 635 or so):

```
set $valid_options["TEXTPERCENT"] "This value forces percentages to be displayed as text";
set $valid_options["TEXTCURRENCY"] "This value forces currency amounts to be displayed as text";
```

That text can be whatever you want, this is one interpretation.  Now, around line 700 there are some lines setting the defaults, add these two:

```
set $option_defaults["TEXTCURRENCY"] 'no';
set $option_defaults["TEXTPERCENT"] 'no';
```

Now down much later (around row 1670) you have the section that defines $punctuation.  We change how that works in order to remove "%" and "$" from the list if you set those options:

```
set $punctuation $thousands_separator " ";
set $punctuation $punctuation "%" /if ^$textpct;
set $punctuation $punctuation $currency_sym /if ^$textcurr;
```

(Basically, set $variable  /if ; we set up punctuation to start with $thousands_separator and then add in the other bits if they are "no" only.)

Now around line 2100 in the "Yes/no on/off options... " section we evaluate the option's value.  (The prior uses these values, but that's okay; it's actually called later.)

```
set $option_key 'TEXTPERCENT';
trigger do_yes_no;
eval $textpct $answer;

set $option_key 'TEXTCURRENCY';
trigger do_yes_no;
eval $textcurr $answer;
```

Finally, we implement things.  Down around line 7400 is `event value_type;` which is where the % $ get removed and the numbers get adjusted to be 'real numbers' even if they shouldn't be.  This is annoying.  So we tell it not to.

```
do /if ^$textpct;
 do /if $convert_percentages;
   eval $tmp inputn($value, $test_format)/100;
 else;
   eval $tmp inputn($value, $test_format);
 done;
 /*putlog "Percent value:" $tmp;*/
 set $value $tmp;
done;
```

We wrap the percent conversion code with `do /if ^$textpct;` and `done`, which tells it to skip doing the inputn (which will kill our percents).  If we were cheating and not doing this the proper way, we could comment out this line:

```
set $value compress($value, $punctuation);
```

But since we fixed the $punctuation variable to contain (or not contain!) the right stuff already, this isn't an issue.

Now this will work!  We just modify the tagset call:

```
*First include your tagset, which I put in c:\temp\ but you can put wherever and call whatever you like;
%include "c:\temp\excel_tpl_nocompress.txt";
 ods tagsets.ExcelXP path="c:\temp\"  file="testfile.xml" 
                    options(frozen_headers='yes' WrapText='no'
                            embedded_titles='yes' suppress_bylines='yes'
                            sheet_interval='none' sheet_label=' ' 
                            sheet_name='Solicited' convert_percentages="no"
                            width_points='1' width_fudge='1' 
                            absolute_column_width='100' autofit_height='yes' 
                            textcurrency='yes' textpercent='yes'
                            zoom='100');
title1;
*Then add in the textpercent and textcurrency lines, and it should work as is.;
```

And now you're off to the races.

```
- <Row ss:AutoFitHeight="1">
- <Cell ss:StyleID="data__l1" ss:Index="1">   <Data ss:Type="String">23.45%</Data>    </Cell>
- <Cell ss:StyleID="data__c1" ss:Index="2">   <Data ss:Type="String" />    </Cell>
- <Cell ss:StyleID="data__l1" ss:Index="3">   <Data ss:Type="String">$0</Data>    </Cell>   
</Row>
```

Comment: I actually have tried adding the single quotation mark and in Excel I get **'$0** instead of **$0**.  Any other ideas?  I can get them to look like I want, but they are then numeric fields in Excel.  I want them to be text fields in Excel.

Comment: Thanks Joe! I found the correct SAS options to fool it into thinking that my currency and decimal symbols were pipes instead of '$' and '.'  It is useful to know that I can look directly at the xml produced to troubleshoot as well.

Comment: @MarkNielsen Updated with the "proper" way to do it, although of course your hack is a good solution as well.

Comment: That did it! I made sure to format them as text in `TAGATTR` and it worked fine!  Thanks!

Comment: Also, there was just one typo, set `$punctuation $puntuation "%" /if ^$textpct;` should be `set $punctuation $punctuation "%" /if ^$textpct;`

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer I needed.  I found the ExcelXP Options on the following page: [ExcelXP Options](http://support.sas.com/rnd/base/ods/odsmarkup/excelxp_help.html)  I know it is a 'hack', but I changed the default options in the `tagsets.ExcelXP` to be `currency_symbol = "|"` and `decimal_separator = "|"`... fooling SAS into thinking that it should look for the pipe for currencies instead of a dollar sign and the pipe instead of a period for percentages.  That way when it came across `$0` or `23.45%` it treated these as pure text.